# Index Error: list index out of range in python

Tags: python

I have project in internet security class. My partner started the project and wrote some python code and i have to continue from where he stopped. But i don't know python and i was planning to learn by running his code and checking how it works. however when i am executing his code i get an error which is "IndexError: list index out of range".

```
import os
# Deauthenticate devices
os.system("python2 ~/Downloads/de_auth.py -s 00:22:b0:07:58:d4 -d & sleep 30; kill $!")
# renew DHCP on linux "sudo dhclient -v -r & sudo dhclient -v"


# Capture DHCP Packet
os.system("tcpdump -lenx -s 1500 port bootps or port bootpc -v > dhcp.txt & sleep 20; kill $!")

# read packet txt file
DHCP_Packet = open("dhcp.txt", "r")

# Get info from txt file of saved packet
line1 = DHCP_Packet.readline()
line1 = line1.split()
sourceMAC = line1[1]
destMAC = line1[3]
TTL = line1[12]
length = line1[8]

#Parse packet
line = DHCP_Packet.readline()
while "0x0100" not in line:
    line = DHCP_Packet.readline()

packet = line + DHCP_Packet.read()

packet = packet.replace("0x0100:", "")
packet = packet.replace("0x0110:", "")
packet = packet.replace("0x0120:", "")
packet = packet.replace("0x0130:", "")
packet = packet.replace("0x0140:", "")
packet = packet.replace("0x0150:", "")
packet = packet.replace("\n", "")
packet = packet.replace(" ", "")
packet = packet.replace("   ", "")
packet = packet.replace("000000000000000063825363", "")

# Locate option (55) = 0x0037
option = "0"
i=0
length = 0 
while option != "37":
    option = packet[i:i+2]
    hex_length = packet[i+2:i+4]
    length = int(packet[i+2:i+4], 16)
    i = i+ length*2 + 4

i = i - int(hex_length, 16)*2
print "Option (55): " + packet[i:i+length*2 ] + "\nLength: " + str(length) + " Bytes"
print "Source MAC: " + sourceMAC
```

Thank you a lot

Comment: What do you think is wrong? Please include the stack trace. If it's "urgent," then what's your budget for a fix?

Comment: (for what it's worth, it looks like your partner doesn't know Python very well, either)

Comment: well it turned out that i had to specify the interface i am using in the linux command. the python code worked just fine. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

The index error probably means you have an empty or undefined section (index) in your lists. It's most likely in the loop condition at the bottom:

```
while option != "37":
    option = packet[i:i+2]
    hex_length = packet[i+2:i+4]
    length = int(packet[i+2:i+4], 16)
    i = i+ length*2 + 4
```

Alternatively, it could be earlier in reading your text file:

```
# Get info from txt file of saved packet
line1 = DHCP_Packet.readline()
line1 = line1.split()
sourceMAC = line1[1]
destMAC = line1[3]
TTL = line1[12]
length = line1[8]
```

Try actually opening the text file and make sure all the lines are referred to correctly.

If you're new to coding and not used to understanding error messages or using a debugger yet, one way to find the problem area is including `print ('okay')` between lines in the code, moving it down progressively until the line no longer prints.

I'm pretty new to python as well, but I find it easier to learn by writing your own code and googling what you want to achieve (especially when a partner leaves you code like that...). This website provides documentation on in-built commands (choose your version at the top): https://docs.python.org/3.4/contents.html,
and this website contains more in-depth tutorials for common functions: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable `line1` that being split does not have as much as 13 numbers,so you will get error when executing statement `TTL = line1[12]`.

Maybe you do not have the same environment as your partner worked with ，so the result you get(file `dhcp.txt`) by executing os.system("") maybe null(or with a bad format). 
You should check the content of the file `dhcp.txt` or add statement `print line1` after `line1 = DHCP_Packet.readline()` to check if it has a correct format.

Comment: Apparently tcpdump was listening on interface eth0 not on wlan1. I changed the mac address and the interface used and it worked. So basically it wasn't capturing any packets and dhcp.txt was empty. Thank you anyways :)